# PHP json_encode() Adding an Apostrophe at Pos 0

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have a very strange issue. I have been working on a project for months with no issues. Today I was coding on the API side of the project and suddenly my json string is returning with a ' at position 0.

The weird part is I have not touched that code for a while. To test I made the API return

```
die(json_encode('hi'));
```

Which returns: `'"hi"` ,but when I try to have javascript parse it using:

```
server.data = JSON.parse(server.data);
```

I get the following error:

```
Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 0
```

I am at a complete loss because nothing has changed on my code. I even rolled back to a commit that was working fine yesterday and still the same issue. Does anyone have a direction they can point me in?

Comment: That's not coming from this code. You probably have an extra `'` earlier in the script. Maybe it's before the `<?php` at the beginning.

Comment: There is only one place I return anything and it's two lines: currently     http_response_code($this->statusCode); die(json_encode('hi'));

Comment: I'm sure you are right though. I'll have to start stepping through it